# How to add a new class to table td?

Tags: angular

I have table structure like following. I want to add a new class into the td next with class profile and remove the previous class on button click. I know how to do it using jquery but I am trying angular 4. Can anybody help me?

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="profile"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="profile"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="profile"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="profile"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: So, you want to change the class from `profile` to something else, or add the class to a different `td` element?

Comment: I want to add a class "profile" to the next td first then remove the class "profile" from previous

Comment: use [ngClass]="{'profile':condition,'':!condition}". where "condition" can be any expresion. if your table are created using a *ngFor, you can use let i=index;let odd=odd...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use ngClass to add classes.
For Ex:

```
<button [ngClass]="{'b1': button1Class}" 
        (click)="button1Clicked()">asdasd</button>
<button [ngClass]="{'b2': button2Class}" 
        (click)="button2Clicked()">bbbbbb</button>

//In Your Typescript
 button1Class = false;
  button2Class = false;

   button1Clicked() {
    this.button1Class = !this.button1Class;
}

 button2Clicked() {
  this.button2Class = !this.button2Class;
}

//In your css
.b1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.b2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

[You can play with this.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hfcyt)

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the DOM elements in typescript. I am providing the simplest example of how can you do it.

On the button click, get the list of all the elements that have "profile" class name. Loop through them to assign the class to next sibling first and then remove it from the existing td.

**file.component.html**

```
<button (click)="btnClick()">click</button>
```

**file.component.ts**

```
    btnClick(){
    let elements: HTMLCollectionOf<Element> =  
   document.getElementsByClassName("profile");
        for(let i=0; i<= elements.length-1; i++){
          elements[i].nextSibling.className = "profile";
          elements[i].className = "";
        }
      }
```